# As I can make a configuration list through a command on java bukkit?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

In this case I am creating a plugin to learn, I need to know the following things.
What I want to do is to establish points on the map and at these points when another command will fall lightning.

1- For example: /thor setpoint 1, 2, 3, 4...

And in config created...

```
Lightning:
  1:
    x:
    y:
    z:
  2:
    x:
    y:
    z:
  3... 6, 14..
```

The next three commands.

- /thor delpoint 1, 2, 3... = Deleted point ID
- /launch all = Launch all points
- /launch ID = Only launch id

For now I managed to fall into a coordinate, single configuration file.

Thanks in advance

Main:

```
package me.alexbanper.thorproject.plugin;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Location;
//import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class ThorProject extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    public void onEnable(){
        saveDefaultConfig();
    }

    public void onDisable(){

    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender enviar, Command comando, String commandLabel, String[] args){
        Player player = (Player) enviar;
        if(enviar instanceof Player){
            if(commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("trueno")){
                if(player.hasPermission("trueno.comando")){
                    if(args.length == 0){
                        player.sendMessage(col("&aUtiliza:"));
                        player.sendMessage(col("&6/trueno iniciarahora &5Inicia los truenos"));
                        player.sendMessage(col("&6/trueno iniciartiempo SEGUNDOS &5Inicia con segundos"));
                        player.sendMessage(col("&6/trueno setpoint &5establece un punto"));
                    }else if(args.length == 1){
                         if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("setpoint")){  
                            this.getConfig().set("Config" + ".Thor" + ".X", player.getLocation().getBlockX());
                            this.getConfig().set("Config" + ".Thor" + ".Y", player.getLocation().getBlockY());
                            this.getConfig().set("Config" + ".Thor" + My".Z", player.getLocation().getBlockZ());
                            //this.getConfig().set("Config" + ".World", player.getLocation().getWorld());
                            saveConfig();
                            player.sendMessage(col("&aSpawnPoint 1 set!"));
                            player.sendMessage("X: " + getConfig().getInt("Config.Thor.X"));
                            player.sendMessage("Y: " + getConfig().getInt("Config.Thor.Y"));
                            player.sendMessage("Z: " + getConfig().getInt("Config.Thor.Z"));
                            player.sendMessage("World: " + getConfig().getString("Config.World"));
                        }else if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("setpoint2")){    
                            this.getConfig().set("Config" + ".Thor2" + ".X", player.getLocation().getBlockX());
                            this.getConfig().set("Config" + ".Thor2" + ".Y", player.getLocation().getBlockY());
                            this.getConfig().set("Config" + ".Thor2" + ".Z", player.getLocation().getBlockZ());
                            //this.getConfig().set("Config" + ".World", player.getLocation().getWorld());
                            saveConfig();
                            player.sendMessage(col("&aSpawnPoint 2 Set!"));
                            player.sendMessage("X: " + getConfig().getInt("Config.Thor2.X"));
                            player.sendMessage("Y: " + getConfig().getInt("Config.Thor2.Y"));
                            player.sendMessage("Z: " + getConfig().getInt("Config.Thor2.Z"));
                            player.sendMessage("World: " + getConfig().getString("Config.World"));
                        }
                    }
                }else{enviar.sendMessage(col("&cAcceso Denegado!"));}
            }else if(commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("it")){
                int x = getConfig().getInt("Config.Thor.X");
                int y = getConfig().getInt("Config.Thor.Y");
                int z = getConfig().getInt("Config.Thor.Z");

                int x2 = getConfig().getInt("Config.Thor2.X");
                int y2 = getConfig().getInt("Config.Thor2.Y");
                int z2 = getConfig().getInt("Config.Thor2.Z");
                //Object world = getConfig().get("Config" + ".World");

                Location light = new Location(null, x, y, z);
                Location light2 = new Location(null, x2, y2, z2);

                Bukkit.getServer().getWorld("world").strikeLightningEffect(light);
                Bukkit.getServer().getWorld("world").strikeLightningEffect(light2);
                player.sendMessage("All correct!");
            }
        }else{enviar.sendMessage("Only Players!");}
        return false;
    }

    public static String col(String msg){
        return ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', msg);
    }
}
```

/trueno = /thor (I speak Spanish)

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: This is no problem, need the 'how to make'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to save the world name too or you cannot get the location at all later. For all, make a call to get the keyset and iterate through all of the locations. (Be careful how you do this, make sure you are using the correct keys) 
Delete the map of the key when you need to delete a location. Lastly, get the corresponding key when selecting a specific ID. 
There are plenty of videos you can google to understand the behavior of Bukkit's YAMLConfigiration class, but most of them are absolutely horrible. I found one that isn't AS bad for you.  It is for config files, but the YAMLConfig class behaves very similarly. (I plan on doing some of my own tutorials this summer, but I am going to be VERY careful with following java conventions and correct practice unlike most of these youtubers)

Bukkit Coding ~ Episode 5: Configuration: https://youtu.be/SBvrpmNDr74

As a side note, the bukkit forums are a better place for bukkit development than stack overflow. 
http://bukkit.org/forums/